# Javascript replacing new line character

Tags: javascript, regex

This is driving me crazy, I have a string in the format:

```
<br />
twice<br />
imap Test wrote:<div class="nestedMessage1"><br />
> nested<br />
><br />
> imap@gazler.com wrote:<div class="nestedMessage2"><br />
>> test<br />
>><br />
>> -- <br />
>> Message sent via AHEM.<br />
>>   </div><br />
><br /><br /></div>
```

And the following code:

```
string = string.replace(/\n/g, "");
string = replaceAll(string, "<br />>", "<br />");

function replaceAll(string, replaceString, replaceWith)
{
  return string.replace(new RegExp(replaceString, 'g'),replaceWith);
}
```

What I am attempting to do is remove the <br />> and replace it with just the <br />  I can't simply replace all occurrences of > as they may be contained elsewhere in the line, so I only want to remove them at the start.  I have tried escape characters and have hardcoded the regular expression to remove the new lines explicitly instead of including them in the function call.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you may have \r's in there, too

Comment: also you have <br />>> not just <br />>

Comment: @peller, as far as I know, javascript ignored the return escape character.

@Jason: The initial code was looped replacing the number of times to the depth of the number of >s.

Comments are always appreciated though.  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your goal is simply to remove all the `>`s at the beginning of the lines, that's easy to do:

```
var out = in.replace(new RegExp("^>+", "mg"), "");
```

or

```
var out = in.replace(/^>+/mg, "");
```

The `m` flag means multi-line so `^` and `$` will match the beginning and end of lines, not just the beginning and end of the string. See [RegExp Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/RegExp).

**Edit:** It's worth mentioning that you should *probably* favour using the `RegExp` object over the second form (regex literal). See [Are /regex/ Literals always RegExp Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326374/are-regex-literals-always-regexp-objects) and [Why RegExp with global flag in Javascript give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results).

In addition there are browser differences in how the global flag is treated on a regex literal that is used more than once. It's best to avoid it and explicitly use a `RegExp` object.

Comment: An elegant solution to the problem.  Much appreciated.