# How to convert \n to HTML line break

Tags: javascript

I am using this plugin to parse bbcode [bbcodeparser](https://github.com/wGEric/phpBB-BBCode-Javascript-Parser)

but it has no functionality to convert `\n` to `<br/>`.

I tried adding this:

```
replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '<br>')
```

...but it didn't work.

How can I implement line break functionality?

Comment: please post jsfiddle link here

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript replacing new line character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136648/javascript-replacing-new-line-character)

Comment: `str.replace(/\r\n|\n|\r/gm, '<br />');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8573890/104380

Answer (score 145):

If you are doing this to show new line and return carriage in html, then you don't need to do it explicitly. You can do it in css by setting the *white-space* attribute *pre-line* value.

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">@Model.CommentText</span>
```

Comment: edit: Although it says it is unsupported in IE, it seems to work okay in IE8 + 11: http://caniuse.com/#search=white-space

Comment: pre-line will also collapse sequences of whitespaces. If you want to preserve whitespaces, try pre-wrap. There are other options as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space?v=example

Comment: I hate when the absolute best answers are at the bottom

Answer (score 17):

The above answer helped me to fix my problem but I dig down a little more and found some additional info about `white-space` properties. I hope it may help someone like me:

**What is `white-space` property:**

> white-space is a CSS property that helps control how whitespace and line breaks within an element's text are treated. It can take these values: normal, nowrap, pre, pre-line, pre-wrap.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

actually, Browsers doesn't treat `\r\n` as real new-lines, in PHP  [nl2br](https://www.php.net/nl2br) used, where as in Javascript you can use below function for `nl2br()` equivalent.

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');}
```

Comment: What does $1 and $2 does here?

Comment: Browser does treat it as new-lines if you specify the correct css style.

Comment: @Foreever: `$1` and `$2` refers to the first and second group in the regexp (a group is something in `()`). So the code will retain the original parts of the string and just insert `<br>` tags before a new line.

Comment: what to specify as argument for `is_xhtml`?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
const regex = /\\n|\\r\\n|\\n\\r|\\r/g;
string.replace(regex, '<br>');
```